# "rel=nofollow noopener" - Possible to have both at the same time?

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, nofollow, noindex

I've got a pdf that I'd like to protect and don't want search engines to index it.

Currently, my link is as follows:

```
<a href="https://example.com/mypdf.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">View PDF</a>
```

Would I be able to add `nofollow` tag to the `rel` tag?

Would I then divide these two with a coma or no coma?

Currently trying `rel=nofollow noopener` without coma.

Would I be able to add `noindex` to the same tag?

```
<a href="https://example.com/mypdf.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noindex noopener">View PDF</a>
```

Would this work?

Comment: Yes you can, please read this alternate answer [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111717/what-is-the-difference-between-nofollow-noopener-vs-just-nofollow)

Answer (score 34):

"**nofollow**" tag tells search engines "don't follow this link."

"**noreferrer**" tag indicates no referrer information to be leaked on this link.

"**noopener**" tag prevents the new page from being able to access the window.opener property (preventing malicious javascript).

you can use both something like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/mypdf.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">View PDF</a>
```

"**noindex**" you can't noindex a link. That would have to be defined on-page, in the meta data.

You're better off blocking pages in robots.txt if that's what you're after.

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /mypdf.pdf
```

Comment: According to [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel) `noreferrer` implies `noopener` but does `noopener` implies `nofollow`(or vice-versa)? I see no info about that but I would like a confirm if it's not implied in any of the both ways.